# How to check which shortcode is using my template?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I'm editing my content-product.php file in my child theme, because i want to create custom woocommerce loops.

For now, i've put everything in a big `if ( is_woocommerce() );`. With an else with my own code inside.

The problem is that now, if i use the shortcode `[product]` and `[best_selling]`, or every other woocommerce shortcode in a page, i get the same (wrong) layout.

So i just need to check which shortcode is calling my template.

Example:
As i said, i have a if ( is_woocommerce() ); condition.

If the page is woocommerce, it will show the default template.

Then there is an else, so every other page loads the 2nd template.

I want to check which shortcode is beign used to load that template, so i can do something like:

```
switch (shortcode_used)

case 'single_product':
    code

case 'best_selling'
    code
```

etc.

Thank you in advance.
-Kryuko

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "wrong layout". edit your question to add more details and examples.

Comment: If you're trying to figure out if the shortcode is loading your template so you can make it do something different, that seems like a suboptimal approach. `content-product.php` is used by WooCommerce, it wouldn't surprise me if any shortcode that displays a product uses that template. So some clarification is needed in your question. What makes it the right or wrong layout?

Comment: As i said, i have a if ( is_woocommerce() ); condition.

If the page is woocommerce, it will show the default template.

Then there is an else, so every other page loads the 2nd template.

I want to check which shortcode is beign used to load that template, so i can do something like:

switch (shortcode_used)

case 'single_product':
 code

case 'best_selling'
 code


etc.

Comment: I've looked at the woocommerce shortcode php file, but i didn't understood how check which shortcode is used.

Comment: I've found the shortcode_atts function, but i didn't understood if i can use it for what i need.